# Simulator become very slow

Tags: ios, simulator

I don't know why, the simulator become very slow no matter switch the interface or animate, but type in `textField`, it is normal, without slow.

[image]

---

**Attempt -1**

I restart Xcode and Simulator, but there is no effect.

---

**Attemp -2**

I clean the project, did not work too.

---

**Attempt -3**

I set the simulator's Graphics Quality Override to Low Quality, also do not work.

Comment: Or press command-T to toggle Slow Animations.

Comment: On simulator press Cmd+T to toggle between slow-motion enabled/disabled

Comment: Animation is slow, press CMD + T .

Comment: Yes, uncheck ` Debug->Slow Animations option ` helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, if Debug->Slow Animations option is enabled

Comment: Yes, I uncheck this, it become normal, I don't know why it is open.